# Spring Boot controller to forward general json

Tags: json, spring

In a Spring Boot controller, I am receiving json and want to "forward" it without any processing:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forward", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void abc(@RequestBody GeneralJsonRepresentation json, HttpServletRequest request) {

        restTemplate.postForEntity(endpoint, json, Object.class)
    }
```

Is it possible to accomplish this, for instance with an implementation of `GeneralJsonRepresentation`, assuming the controller has no knowledge of the json format and that the received content type is `application/json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not even need the `GeneralJsonRepresentation` if you just use a `String`.

I created a small working snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/forward", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> forward(@RequestBody String postData) {
    // maybe needed configuration
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().basicAuthorization("user", "password").build();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(postData, headers);

    final String targetUrl = "http://targethost/endpoint";
    final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(targetUrl, entity, String.class);

    return ResponseEntity.created(...).build();
}
```